# Eclipse CDT C++ как нормально настроить компиляцию

Tags: c++, eclipse, cdt

Есть простейшая программа:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout<<("Author") << endl;
    cout<<2+2;
    return 0;
}
```

Если нажимать Run (alt+f11) - компилируется и выводиться в консоль информация, но если добавить что-то в код (создать ошибку), Run запускает последнюю удачную конфигурацию, то есть написав:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout<<("Author") << endl;
    cout<<2vwetew+2;
    return 0;
}
```

всё равно компилируется и выводит:
Author
4
, но мне нужно, чтобы в консоли выводились ошибки, как при написании java программы. Вроде стоит build automatically и build project говорит, что ошибка, но run происходит. На java есть правильно написанная программа -> результат в консоли, случайно добавил символ к переменной и нажимаешь alt+f11 -> ошибка компиляции, надо, чтобы точно так же было с C++.

Answer (score 0):

Открываете окно настроек запуска: Window → Preferences → Run / Debug → Launching в группе Continue launch if project contains errors выбираете Prompt.